# How can remove markdown table alignment when I use pandas.to_markdown

Tags: python, pandas, markdown

**Thank you for your consideration.**

## Summarize the problem

When I transfer talbe from excel to markdown I use pandas library.

1. Copy table in excel to clipboard.
2. Make a dataframe by pd.read_clipboard
3. Make str(markdown table) by pd.to_markdown

Str from pd.to_markdown alwasy applied alignment.

But I want to remove alignment in markdown table when I make str by pd.to_markdown.

here are some example.

### text from clipboard

```
post_it width   height
653 51  38
654 76  76
656 76  51
657 102 76
```

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_clipboard()
markdown_table=df.to_markdown(index=False)
```

```py
print(df)
```

```
   post_it  width  height
0      653     51      38
1      654     76      76
2      656     76      51
3      657    102      76
```

```py
print(markdown_table)
```

### What I recived from pd.to_markdown

```
|   post_it |   width |   height |
|----------:|--------:|---------:|
|       653 |      51 |       38 |
|       654 |      76 |       76 |
|       656 |      76 |       51 |
|       657 |     102 |       76 |
```

### What I want data from pd.to_markdown

#### There is no colon symbol 2nd line

```
|   post_it |   width |   height |
|-----------|---------|----------|
|       653 |      51 |       38 |
|       654 |      76 |       76 |
|       656 |      76 |       51 |
|       657 |     102 |       76 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `to_markdown()` method has a `tablefmt` parameter.

This looks like what you want:

```py
print(df.to_markdown(tablefmt="github", index=False))

# Output

|   post_it |   width |   height |
|-----------|---------|----------|
|       653 |      51 |       38 |
|       654 |      76 |       76 |
|       656 |      76 |       51 |
|       657 |     102 |       76 |
```

There are many formats to choose from if this isn't what you want. They're listed in the docs: https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate